# Are setHeader and writeHead connected?

Tags: node.js

In the code below if I uncomment the res.setHeader("name","Alim") then the res.getHeaders shows all the headers as the content of an object. But if the setHeaders line is commented (or not used) the writeHead doesn't seem to work and I get an empty object when using getHeaders(). This is not a critical issue as I am just experimenting but I am trying to figure out what is the connection. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const http = require("http");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
//  res.setHeader("name", "Alim");
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    Authorization: "Header 123456",
  });
  res.write('Yes....')

  res.end("Hello World..");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res.getHeaders()));
});

server.listen(3000, "localhost", () => {
  console.log("Server Running.....");
});
```

Comment: I tried to come up with an answer but not even I am sure why this happens. I'm curious of the answer, if anyone can answer it!

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a450eedffade72d31624dbbd9171ac87b28c436a/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L458) for `writeHead()` `setHeader()` and `getHeaders()` that `getHeaders()` only retrieves the headers that are set with `setHeader()` and are this stored in `this[kOutHeaders]` for future use.

It does not retrieve headers that are included with `res.writeHeader()`.

I presume the general idea is that `getHeaders()` is retrieving any headers that are queued up and have already been manually set for this response (before the response has been sent).  It is not coded to tell you all the headers that were already sent for this response and thus does not include the headers you pass with `.writeHead()`.